# DNS CNAME for a SQL Managed Instance (Azure)

Tags: sql-server, azure, network, dns, azure-sql-managed-instance

I currently have an on Prem SQL Instance that has a DNS CNAME set up against it via our On Prem DNS Server.

I am looking to move this server to an Azure Managed Instance and I want to point the DNS CNAME at this server (the MI is in a VNet that is connected to our internal network)

In my testing if I create a new DNS CNAME at the Manage Instance Host ServerName.dnsPrefix.database.windows.net it works from SSMS but not from any of our apps. I think it’s some sort of reverse lookup issue. If I point the App directly at the MI host (ServerName.dnsPrefix.database.windows.net) it works fine.

Is it not possible to point a on Prem DNS CNAME at an Azure MI?

Comment: I too would love to be able to do this.  We were unable to get it working for our environment and had to use the servername/listener name directly.

Comment: See the open issue here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915676-sql-managed-instance/suggestions/38016925-support-dns-aliasing-of-an-azure-sql-managed-insta